# IP webcam in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, mac, webcam, camera

Is there any way to access the video and sound of my Mac. I'd like to use it as a security cam and access it remotely from a web browser. How to do it?

Answer (score 1):

I've played with the following :

http://www.evological.com/evocam.html

It can upload your pictures taken with your isight on an FTP server so you can display it on a webpage.

Or you can store the picture locally and serve them via apache running on your machine !

Answer (score 0):

[Periscope](http://www.freeverse.com/mac/product/?id=7002) from Freeverse also helps. Pretty cool interface too. According to the product page, it sends live images to your e-mail, Mobile Me webpage, or FTP server. It can also upload to Flickr, but I don't think it's a good idea to do that though. (Flickr's public.)